# Change VNC boot configuration in Raspbian Jessie

Tags: raspbian, vnc, vnc-server

When I boot my Pi 3 connected to a monitor, the built-in VNC server loads with the monitor's resolution.  When I boot the Pi 3 without a monitor connected, it defaults to a much lower resolution.

I've found this lower resolution extremely difficult to code on as I can't see very much of my code at once.

Is there any way to set a configuration file and specify the resolution the VNC server launches at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found after more digging:

The boot configuration in Raspbian (I'm using Jessie) needed to be modified.

To do this I ran `sudo nano /boot/config.txt` in terminal to open the file as superuser in nano.

I changed (un-commented) the following lines:

```
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_group=1
hdmi_mode=16
```

mode=16 is standard 1080p IIRC

Modes can be found here: [Raspberry Pi Configuration](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt.md)

From what I understand, what we're doing is forcing the Pi to boot as if a monitor were connected, then specifying the resolution.